# Interrupt kernel process or another interrupt

Tags: linux, interrupt, mips

How does ISR know that it interrupts process in kernel mode or another interrupt (which enables further interrupts) - of course in kernel mode too.

If this question is very wide, please aim to Linux on MIPS.

Comment: What evidence did you find that ISR's _do_ know what they are interrupting?  Or, do you mean to ask how an ISR _could_ know?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a common function (not sure whether it's more than a convention) `die_if_kernel`, which illustrates this.

The MIPS implementation checks `regs` (saved registers from before the interrupt) as passed to the ISR, using the predicate function `user_mode()`.

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/mips/include/asm/ptrace.h?v=4.12#L169

I thought to look in places like this, as traps/faults are often considered fatal when they occur inside the kernel.

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/mips/kernel/traps.c#L1230